# Passing from a UITableView to another with PrepareForSegue method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm a junior iOS developer.
Currently I'm working on an app, and I want to create settings, so I have a UITableViewController that contains a UITableView with categories, and when you click on a cell, you should display another UITableView that contains all values for the clicked category.
Here is the code :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{

if segue.identifier == "getValueFromCategory" {
  let viewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? UnitTableViewController)!

  let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
  print(indexPath)
  segue.
  //print(viewController)
  viewController!.toPass = self.categories[indexPath].titleCategory
}
}
```

If I uncomment the let viewController line, I got this error : Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x10b635c10) to 'fitness.UnitTableViewController' (0x108196d48).

If anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong, it could help !

Thanks !

Comment: please post both current class name and destination class name and its properties

Comment: Why not using didSelectedRowAtIndex to go on another ViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you have said, is in these lines:

```
if segue.identifier == "getValueFromCategory" {
  let viewController = (segue.destinationViewController as? UnitTableViewController)!
```

The error message tells you that the destinationViewController of this segue is not, in fact, a UnitTableViewController. You may think it is, but it isn't. You need to examine this segue in the storyboard and see what's really at the destination end of it.

The fact that the error message describes it as a UIViewController makes me suspect that you forgot to enter any view controller type in this view controller's Identity inspector in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer which very clear.
I don't know why, but on the storyboard, I can't access to these information
That only writes "No Selection" you have any idea why ?
I was looking for trying your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{

    let objNextViewController : NextViewController =  segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController

    // objNextViewController.array = currentClassArray

}
```

Or

Approach 2

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

 let objNextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“ID_NextViewController”) as? NextViewController

 // objNextViewController.array = currentClassArray

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objNextViewController!, animated: true)

}
```